# How would one optimize the curl library for size?

Tags: c++, curl, hyperlink, static, libcurl

I've been attempting to shrink the size of my file for the past week or so, during that time I have discovered some compiler options that could drastically shrink the size of my file.
 However, due to my static implementation of libcurl, my file is still around 2.3mb; I would like to change that.
 I have searched other thread on various forums and found that on linux you could build the libcurl library with HTTP only enabled, however, my app is to run specifically on Windows.
 I am using the CodeBlocks IDE with the MinGW Compiler and these are my configuration settings:

[Link Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ9pd.png)

I have tried removing some of those linked libraries, however, that just results in compiler errors.

Comment: You surely don't need to statically link the Windows runtimes, GDI, OpenSSL etc?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too but when I try to un-link any of the libs I get "Undefined reference to 'blah blah'" example:

Comment: I didn't say you don't need to link them. I'm saying you don't need to link them _statically_.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with linking in C++. If you're saying that I should link them dynamically how would I do so?

Comment: Which textbook are you using?

Answer (score 1):

libcurl supports a lot of protocols, e.g. http, https, ftp, etc(See libcurl website for full list), so try to rebuild the libcurl library after removing unnecessary protocols and keeping only those which you are using in your project. This will reduce size of libcurl significantly.